# How can I pass the result of a command to another command in one line?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, concatenation, command-line-interface

How can I pass minutes since midnight to a `cli` in one line?

This works:

```
echo $[ ( ( `date "+%s"` - 28800 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ]
// Correctly returns minutes since midnight in PST
```

But how can I pass the same into another command?

This doesn't work:

```
my_cli --json '{"minutes" : ' $[ ( ( `date \"+%s\"` - 28800 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ] '}'
```

Returns:

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
ERROR: "my_cli json" was called with arguments ["-300", "}"]
Usage: "my_cli json"
```

I also tried:

```
my_cli --json "{\"minutes\" : \$[ ( ( $(date "+%s") - 28800 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ] }"
```

And I received the following error:

```
...unexpected token at '{"connection" : $[ ( ( 1432139956 - 28800 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ] }' (JSON::ParserError)`
```

Comment: Using modern shell syntax will help here. Use `$(...)` instead of backticks (then you don't need to escape the inner double quotes) and use `$((...))` instead of `$[...]`. See if you can make that work. (That original gets an error for me about the quotes in the date format.)

Comment: You're correct, the original had an error. Didn't need to escape the `"`.

Comment: Why do you believe the second example needs them? Are you trying to get them into the constructed json script? If so put them in the single quoted string or use `+\"%s\"`, date needs to see the `+` as the first thing in the argument.

Comment: The quoting type is a problem here too. Can't get expansions inside single quotes.

Comment: BTW, using string concatenation to build JSON isn't a great practice in general, though it's safe here, where the variables being substituted in will only ever be numeric; when input types are less well-constrained than this, it would be better to use jq, jsawk, or a similar tool.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, where'd your answer go? I think you had it! Was just heading for upvote.

Comment: @Ryan, I removed it since rici was on the right track, so mine was duplicative. That said, I can go ahead and test and re-add it.

Comment: BTW, if you want GNU date on OS X, that's doable; macports &c. will install `gdate` (I think as part of `coreutils`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of minutes should be an integer rather than a string:

```
my_cli --json '{"minutes" : '"$(( ( ( $(date +%s) - 18000 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ))"' }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following provides minutes since midnight for any timezone, with the proviso that "midnight" and "now" might have different time zone offsets:

```
$(( ($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d$(date +%Y-%m-%d))) / 60 ))
```

(I've used the forms `$((...))` and `$(...)` instead of the obsolete and deprecated `$[...]` and `` `...` ``.)

You probably need to provide a single argument to your CLI, so you need to be careful with quoting. For example:

```
my_cli --json "{\"minutes\" : $(( ($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d$(date +%Y-%m-%d))) / 60 ))}"
```

Comment: This looks promising except I receive the `date: illegal time format` error on Mac OS X. (For the first minutes since midnight command)

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, mac os x has a completely different argument convention. I don't think `-d` works on macosx either, and you'll need to either adjust the date format or the parsing format (see the `-f` flag). I don't have a mac handy to play with.

Comment: @Ryan: If I'm reading the manpage correctly, this might work: `$(date +%s -f%Y-%m-%d $(date +%Y-%m-%d))` (for the part following the minus sign)